# Cannot make connection to SQL Server via ODBC

Tags: c++, sql-server, connection, odbc, ado

In the past, I have used ADO to access SQL Server, the connection string for the ADO connection object is:

```
Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=MYPC;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

where MYPC is the name of my computer, and SQL Server is installed on my computer as the default instance.

The above connection string works well.

However, now it is said that ADO is outdated and ODBC is recommended again by Microsoft (see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlnativeclient/2011/08/29/microsoft-is-aligning-with-odbc-for-native-relational-data-access/ ), so I have to modify my code to use ODBC instead.

So I changed the connection to SQL Server to the following code:

```
    CDatabase Database;

    //  Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=MYPC;Integrated Security=SSPI;
    Database.OpenEx(_T("Driver = {SQL Native Client}; Server = MYPC; Trusted_Connection = yes;"), CDatabase::noOdbcDialog);

    Database.ExecuteSQL(_T("create database [MyDB2019] on primary (name=[MyDB2019_File],filename='F:\\MyDB2019.mdf')"));

    Database.Close();
```

However, this code does not work. After executing `Database.OpenEx`, there will be a CDBException indicating

> Data source name not found and no default driver specified.

Why?

Note: I am using Visual C++ 2008 and ADO

Comment: "Now it is said that ADO is outdated and ODBC is recommended again by MS" - do you have any references for this statement?

Comment: I was going to call this out as well. There are specific sql requirements for ODBC that will differ from native sql server, so you are likely up for more than just changing the connection.

Comment: see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlnativeclient/2011/08/29/microsoft-is-aligning-with-odbc-for-native-relational-data-access/ and https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e696d0ac-f8e2-4b19-8a08-7a357d3d780f/microsoft-is-aligning-with-odbc-for-native-relational-data-access-faq?forum=sqldataaccess

Comment: That is a very old reference, and we as a community have been going great guns since then!! The very first line says `EDIT (3/30/2018): OLE DB is now undeprecated.`

Comment: @TomC, so does that mean we can continue use OLE DB?

Comment: @DaleK, I am using Visual C++ 2008 and ADO, not ADO.net

Comment: I'm not sure what you would use from C++ as I am pretty much always using system.data.sqlclient which is using ado.net. I'll let someone else take that detail. But from my reading of the first document you reference the decision was reversed. IMO its unlikely anything like this will go away as they are used in millions of apps. And as I said, changing to an ODBC connection may have other effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error/exception is pointing to the problem (albeit it seems a bit generic at first).

"Data source name not found and no default driver specified"

> Data source name not found --> You did not specify a DSN, you do not
>   want to use a DSN, ignore this part

.

> and no default driver specified --> You intend to use a driver, so this part of the error most likely applies to you.
>
> The connection string appears syntactically correct: "Driver={*Driver Name*}...", so the next
>   step is to check whether the driver you try to use, named SQL Native Client, exists
>   on your machine.

"SQL Native Client" was/is the driver name for SQL Server 2005.
From SQL2008 the driver **name** got a **version descriptor**.

```
Driver={SQL Native Client}             ,sql2005   
Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0} ,sql2008  
Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0} ,sql2012 and later  
Driver={ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server} ,sql2012 and later, odbc appears in the name
Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}  
Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}
```

An easy way to find the installed 'SQL Native' and 'ODBC Driver for SQL Server' drivers on your machine, would be to run the ODBC Data Source Administrator. Type Odbc data sources in your search box or odbcad32.exe in the command/address bar  (for 64bit: %windir%\system32\odbcad32.exe)

When in ODBC Data Source Administrator, switch to the Drivers tab and there you will find all the available/installed drivers, at your disposal.

Here is a powershell script that opens a connection to localhost using odbc. Adjust accordingly to your installed driver(s)

```
cls
$conn = new-object system.data.odbc.odbcconnection 
$conn.connectionstring = 
# all these installed on my pc and working
#"Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=localhost; Database=master;Trusted_Connection=yes;" 
#"Driver={SQL Server};Server=localhost; Database=master;Trusted_Connection=yes;" 
#"Driver={ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server};Server=localhost; Database=master;Trusted_Connection=yes;" 
"Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=localhost; Database=master;Trusted_Connection=yes;" 

$conn.Open()
$conn.State
$conn.Close();
```

..and an mfc button

```
void CMFCDBTestDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    CDatabase database;
    CString connectionstring = _T("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=localhost;Trusted_Connection=yes;");
    CString messagetext;

    TRY{
        //database.Open(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, connectionstring, FALSE); //ok
        database.OpenEx(connectionstring, CDatabase::noOdbcDialog); //ok

        if (database.IsOpen()){
            messagetext = _T("open, database:") + database.GetDatabaseName();
            database.Close();
        }
   }CATCH(CDBException, e) {
       messagetext = _T("Database error: ")+e->m_strError;
   }
   END_CATCH;

   AfxMessageBox(messagetext, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I try to change the driver to {SQL Server Native Client 10.0} but still get the same exception.

Comment: Do I always need to specify the database part? I only want to build a connection but do not open or create any database at the beginning.

Comment: You need to check the installed odbc drivers on your machine. I have tried both older Native Clients 10&11, with Open() and OpenEx() and they worked fine. You do not have to explicitly define a database in the connection string, in such case the default db of the login is used (by default it is the master db). It is not clear how you defined  "building a connection". When you call OpenEx() you are actively establishing/making a connection to sql server.  A connection can never be in the "void" it always "ends up" to a database.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file with udl extension. Example: test.udl
Double click the file. Use the GUI to connect to your database. Once done, open the UDL file using notepad and extract the connection string.

See https://www.dmxzone.com/go/312/how-to-generate-an-ado-connection-string/

Comment: Is there a way to make the connection without creating a file? Your method is a bit inconvenient.

Comment: Well, this is just an automatic way to get the connection string. Open the file using notepad and you get the connection string ready to be pasted in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the extra spaces in the connection string, after removing extra spaces from:

"Driver = {SQL Native Client}; Server = MYPC; Trusted_Connection = yes;"

to(and change the driver name as well):

"Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=MYPC;Trusted_Connection=yes;"

The connection will succeed.